# Single quote needed to make an html element a string

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a button element that I need to be converted to a string. Here it is below and notice the single quote on both sides, that's the character I'm using to make the button element a string (where it cannot do any event because it's just a string).

```
'<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" href='@Url.Action("CategoryForm", "Category",new {id = Model.Id })' data-target="#AddCategoryModal" class="btn-edit btn btn-info btn-default">Edit</button>'
```

My problem is below, URL action is included inside the button tag but it's not becoming a string, where should I put the single quote for this?

```
href='@Url.Action("CategoryForm", "Category",new {id = Model.Id })'
```

I'm using RAZOR MVC View.

Comment: ...what? Could you give a [mcve]?

Comment: can i ask why are you converting a button tag in string?

Comment: not sure about this use case, but can't you just escape the `'` by `\'`

Comment: jonrsharpe , you can copy that line of code at the very top and paste it to your MVC view , youll find that @URL.Action is left out on becoming a string, the color should change right, if its a string it should colored red , what happened is that url.action is still black colored font

Comment: im converting a button to a string because i need to append it to a table

Answer (score 0):

```
'<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" href=\'@Url.Action("CategoryForm", 
"Category",new {id = Model.Id })\' data-target="#AddCategoryModal" class="btn-
 edit btn btn-info btn-default">Edit</button>'
```

or

```
 `<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" href='@Url.Action("CategoryForm", 
 "Category",new {id = Model.Id })' data-target="#AddCategoryModal" class="btn-
 edit btn btn-info btn-default">Edit</button>`
```

Comment: IT ALMOST WORKED, except the Model.Id , it should be replaced with arr[0], how? My arr[0] contains the Id and not the Model.Id, theres a red underline showing when im putting arr[0] like  {id = arr[0]}

Comment: How to do this Url.Action using Javascript? or jquey